# How to access a class property that starts with a literal $

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object ( [$t] => DumDum )
```

How can I get the string "DumDum", if the object is called $title?

I tried `$title->t; $title->$t`. It comes from Youtube API, I did not created the class.

```
 [title] => stdClass Object
 (
     [$t] => DumDum
 )
```

Comment: Hm, how'd you end up with a property named literally `$t`?  It should be possible with `$title->{'$t'}` single quoting it inside `{}`

Comment: If you have any control over the generation of this object, I'd strongly recommend making it such that the property doesn't get a literal `$` in its name.

Comment: @Michael Youtube data api gives me the object.

Comment: an odd index indeed, anyway just access it property normally: `echo $title->{'$t'}`

Comment: @user2997779 Definitely confusing. They chose a name that results in needing to use one of the most confusing and poorly documented features of PHP object properties :)

Comment: If you got this from `json_decode()` for example, you could pass `true` to the second parameter to at least force it into an associative array rather than a stdClass object. That way you avoid the `{}` and could use `$title['$t']`, but the single quoting is still needed.  You could also cast this to an array to get the same result:  `$title = (array)$title;`